# How to avoid naming collision with nested structs in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, namespaces

```
struct Avatar: View {
    var body: some View {
        Avatar.Circle() //Name conflict avoided.
    }

    struct Circle: View {
        var body: some View {
            Circle().fill(Color.red) //Name conflict. How to avoid?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually quiet simple, by prefixing with SwiftUI.

```
SwiftUI.Circle()
```

Comment: How about using CircleView?

Comment: If it happened in a big project it would be very confusing and unexpected for other developers in a team (especially after some time) to meet that `Circle` is not a `Circle`.... Just don't duplicate system types.... It is hardly believable that you redefine `UIView` and use `UIKit.UIView`.

Comment: That would of-course avoid name collision all together. So it's good that you mention it. I am also wondering why Apple has chosen Rectangle and not RectangleShape, CircleShape and NavigationView.

Comment: @Asperi it's the whole point of the context right SwiftUI.Circle or an Avatar.Circle. The prefix is what avoids the confusing wouldn't it?